# Why doesn't my form submission handler work?

Tags: forms

I am new to drupal and require help from Gurus.

I am adding some form elements in the status share form by using `hook_form_alter()`. These elements are getting displayed in the form, but my submission handler is not working. I am using `$form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_form_submit';` to add it to the form.

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "statuses_box") {
    $form['tech2'] = array(
      '#type'=>'select',
      '#title' => '',
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('tech2')),     
      '#options' => array('All'=>'All','New'=>'New',),  
      '#multiple' => false,     
    );

    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_form_submit';
  }
}

function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Do something here.
}
```

1. The issue I am getting is `my_module_form_submit` is not getting called. The debugger break-point is not getting hit in this function
2. I am not getting error message neither on page nor in admin/reports/dblog
3. What I want is to add a new row in my custom data table, which this code is supposed to create.
4. Default form handling is running perfectly.

Comment: The default submit handler is sometimes (often even) on a specific element in `$form['actions']`. Does the form you're altering have any submit buttons under `$form['actions']`?

Comment: I'd *try* adding your submit handler BEFORE any current ones. For example: `$form['#submit'] = array_unshift($form['#submit'], my_module_form_submit)`. I'm sure I've had this before, where SOMETHING a submit function does would prevent any more from firing.  I might be thinking of something else though, which is why this is a comment ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Check your form id. I doubt your form id is not correct. Even you can try this also -

```
function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Do something here.
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($form);
  exit;
}
```